# Не устанавливается sudo apt install software-properties-common

Tags: ubuntu

Я мучаюсь с Ubuntu контейнером на Proxmox. Пытаясь установить пайтон 3.9, меня посылают в далёкие края, ведь сначала нужно установить software-properties-common. Устанавливая его, я получаю:

```
sudo: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE): Operation not permitted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dirmngr
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent
  gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gsettings-desktop-schemas
  libappstream4 libasn1-8-heimdal libassuan0 libbrotli1 libdconf1 libglib2.0-bin
  libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer1.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libksba8 libldap-2.4-2
  libldap-common libnpth0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libproxy1v5
  libroken18-heimdal libsoup2.4-1 libstemmer0d libwind0-heimdal packagekit
  packagekit-tools pinentry-curses policykit-1 python3-certifi python3-chardet
  python3-idna python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket
  python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 unattended-upgrades
Suggested packages:
  pinentry-gnome3 tor parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon gstreamer1.0-tools appstream
  pinentry-doc python3-cryptography python3-openssl python3-socks bsd-mailx
  needrestart
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dirmngr
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent
  gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gsettings-desktop-schemas
  libappstream4 libasn1-8-heimdal libassuan0 libbrotli1 libdconf1 libglib2.0-bin
  libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer1.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libksba8 libldap-2.4-2
  libldap-common libnpth0 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libproxy1v5
  libroken18-heimdal libsoup2.4-1 libstemmer0d libwind0-heimdal packagekit
  packagekit-tools pinentry-curses policykit-1 python3-certifi python3-chardet
  python3-idna python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket
  python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 software-properties-common
  unattended-upgrades
0 upgraded, 55 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6616 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dbus-user-session amd64 1.12.16-2ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libdconf1 amd64 0.36.0-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dconf-service amd64 0.36.0-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dconf-gsettings-backend amd64 0.36.0-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libassuan0 amd64 2.5.3-7ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gpgconf amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libksba8 amd64 1.3.5-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libroken18-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libasn1-8-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libheimbase1-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libhcrypto4-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libwind0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libhx509-5-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libkrb5-26-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libheimntlm0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgssapi3-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libnpth0 amd64 1.6-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dirmngr amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpackagekit-glib2-18 amd64 1.1.13-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 amd64 1.1.13-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libproxy1v5 amd64 0.4.15-10
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 glib-networking-common all 2.64.1-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 glib-networking-services amd64 2.64.1-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gsettings-desktop-schemas all 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 glib-networking amd64 2.64.1-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gnupg-l10n all 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gnupg-utils amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gpg amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 pinentry-curses amd64 1.1.0-3build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gpg-agent amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gpg-wks-client amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gpg-wks-server amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gpgsm amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gnupg all 2.2.19-3ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.7-6build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsoup2.4-1 amd64 2.70.0-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libstemmer0d amd64 0+svn585-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libappstream4 amd64 0.12.10-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.64.2-1~fakesync1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgstreamer1.0-0 amd64 1.16.2-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpolkit-agent-1-0 amd64 0.105-26ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 policykit-1 amd64 0.105-26ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 packagekit amd64 1.1.13-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 packagekit-tools amd64 1.1.13-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-certifi all 2019.11.28-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-chardet all 3.0.4-4build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-idna all 2.8-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-urllib3 all 1.25.8-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-requests all 2.22.0-2ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-requests-unixsocket all 0.2.0-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.98.9
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.98.9
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 unattended-upgrades all 2.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus-user-session_1.12.16-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dconf/libdconf1_0.36.0-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dconf/dconf-service_0.36.0-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dconf/dconf-gsettings-backend_0.36.0-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libassuan/libassuan0_2.5.3-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpgconf_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libk/libksba/libksba8_1.3.5-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libroken18-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libasn1-8-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libheimbase1-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libhcrypto4-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libwind0-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libhx509-5-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libkrb5-26-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libheimntlm0-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libgssapi3-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-common_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/npth/libnpth0_1.6-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/dirmngr_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/packagekit/libpackagekit-glib2-18_1.1.13-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/packagekit/gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0_1.1.13-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1v5_0.4.15-10_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib-networking/glib-networking-common_2.64.1-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib-networking/glib-networking-services_2.64.1-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gsettings-desktop-schemas/gsettings-desktop-schemas_3.36.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib-networking/glib-networking_2.64.1-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg-l10n_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg-utils_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpg_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pinentry/pinentry-curses_1.1.0-3build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpg-agent_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpg-wks-client_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpg-wks-server_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpgsm_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/brotli/libbrotli1_1.0.7-6build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsoup2.4/libsoup2.4-1_2.70.0-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/snowball/libstemmer0d_0+svn585-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/appstream/libappstream4_0.12.10-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-bin_2.64.2-1~fakesync1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer1.0/libgstreamer1.0-0_1.16.2-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/policykit-1/libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-26ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/policykit-1/policykit-1_0.105-26ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/packagekit/packagekit_1.1.13-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/packagekit/packagekit-tools_1.1.13-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certifi/python3-certifi_2019.11.28-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/chardet/python3-chardet_3.0.4-4build1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-idna/python3-idna_2.8-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-urllib3/python3-urllib3_1.25.8-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/requests/python3-requests_2.22.0-2ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-requests-unixsocket/python3-requests-unixsocket_0.2.0-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python3-software-properties_0.98.9_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.98.9_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_2.3_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Temporary failure resolving

означает, что у вас проблема с DNS. Система не может разрешить доменное имя в IP-адрес

Попрбуйте проверить на компьютере:

```
# ping archive.ubuntu.com

# host archive.ubuntu.com
```